# competitve programming Dijkstra

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

can any one tell me where is the error in this program please it will be really helpful , i did my best to solve this problem ,this code is passing only two test cases
Given an undirected graph and a starting node, determine the lengths of the shortest paths from the starting node to all other nodes in the graph. If a node is unreachable, its distance is -1. Nodes will be numbered consecutively from  to , and edges will have varying distances or lengths.
Here is the question https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dijkstrashortreach/problem

```
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <stdlib.h> 
    #pragma warning(disable:4996)
    // Node 
    typedef struct node {
        int data;

        // Lower values indicate higher priority 
        int priority;

        struct node* next;

    } Node;

    // Function to Create A New Node 
    Node* newNode(int d, int p)
    {
        Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        temp->data = d;
        temp->priority = p;
        temp->next = NULL;

        return temp;
    }

    // Return the value at head 
    int peek(Node** head)
    {
        return (*head)->data;
    }

    // Removes the element with the 
    // highest priority form the list 
    void pop(Node** head)
    {
        Node* temp = *head;
        (*head) = (*head)->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    void updateprt(Node** head, int data) {
        if ((*head)->data == data)
        {
            Node* temp = *head;
            *head = (*head)->next;
            free(temp);
            return;
        }
        Node* prev = *head;

        while ((prev->next)->data != data) {
            prev = prev->next;
        }
        Node* start = prev->next;
        prev->next = start->next;
        free(start);

    }

    // Function to push according to priority 
    void push(Node** head, int d, int p)
    {
        Node* start = (*head);

        // Create new Node 
        Node* temp = newNode(d, p);
        if (*head == NULL) {
            *head = temp;
            return;
        }
        // Special Case: The head of list has lesser 
        // priority than new node. So insert new 
        // node before head node and change head node. 
        if ((*head)->priority > p) {

            // Insert New Node before head 
            temp->next = *head;
            (*head) = temp;
        }
        else {

            // Traverse the list and find a 
            // position to insert new node 
            while (start->next != NULL &&
                start->next->priority < p) {
                start = start->next;

            }

            // Either at the ends of the list 
            // or at required position 
            temp->next = start->next;
            start->next = temp;
        }
    }

    // Function to check is list is empty 
    int isEmpty(Node** head)
    {
        return (*head) == NULL;
    }
    struct adjlistnode {
        int data;
        struct adjlistnode* next;
    };
    struct adjlist {
        struct adjlistnode* head;
    };
    struct graph {
        int v;
        struct adjlist* array;
    };
    struct graph* creategraph(int v) {
        struct graph* G = (struct graph*) malloc(sizeof(struct graph));
        G->v = v;
        int i;
        G->array = (struct adjlist*)malloc(sizeof(struct adjlist)*v);
        for (i = 0; i < v; i++) {
            G->array[i].head = NULL;
        }
        return G;
    }
    int  Distance[100000], path[50];
    struct adjlistnode* getnewnode(int ver) {
        struct adjlistnode* newnode = (struct adjlistnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct adjlistnode));
        newnode->data = ver;
        newnode->next = NULL;
        return newnode;

    }
    void addedge(struct graph* G, int src, int dest, long int w, long int** weight) {
        struct adjlistnode* temp;
        temp = getnewnode(dest);
        temp->next = G->array[src].head;
        G->array[src].head = temp;

        temp = getnewnode(src);
        temp->next = G->array[dest].head;
        G->array[dest].head = temp;
        if (weight[src][dest] != 0 || weight[dest][src] != 0 && w < weight[src][dest]) {
            weight[src][dest] = w;
            weight[dest][src] = w;
        }
        if (weight[src][dest] == 0) {
            weight[src][dest] = w;
            weight[dest][src] = w;
        }
    }
    void printgraph(struct graph* G) {
        for (int i = 0; i < G->v; i++) {
            struct adjlistnode* temp = G->array[i].head;
            printf("%d->   ", i);
            while (temp) {
                printf(" %d", temp->data);
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    void Dijkstra(Node** queue, struct graph* G, int s, long int** weight) {
        int v, w, d;
        push(queue, s, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            Distance[i] = -1;
        }
        Distance[s] = 0;
        while (!isEmpty(queue)) {
            v = peek(queue);
            pop(queue);
            struct adjlistnode* temp = G->array[v].head;
            while (temp) {
                w = temp->data;
                d = Distance[v] + weight[v][w];

                //To update the distance of w check the below two conditions
                if (Distance[w] == -1) {
                    Distance[w] = d;
                    push(queue, w, d);
                    path[w] = v;
                }
                if (Distance[w] > d)
                {
                    Distance[w] = d;

                    path[w] = v;
                    updateprt(queue, w);
                    push(queue, w, d);


                }
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
    }


    int main()
    {
        int t;
        scanf("%d", &t);
        while (t) {

            Node* pq = NULL;

            int v;
            int e;
            scanf("%d %d", &v, &e);
            long int** weight = (long int**)malloc(sizeof(long int*)*v);
            for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)
                weight[i] = (long int*)malloc(sizeof(long int)*v);
            struct graph* G = creategraph(v);
            int u, w;
            long int l;
            for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
                scanf("%d %d %ld", &u, &w, &l);
                addedge(G, u - 1, w - 1, l, weight);
            }

            int s;
            scanf("%d", &s);
            //    printgraph(G);
                //printf("\n");
            Dijkstra(&pq, G, s - 1, weight);
            for (int i = 0; i < G->v; i++) {
                if (i == s - 1)
                    continue;
                printf("%d ", Distance[i]);
            }
            /*    while (!isEmpty(&pq)) {
                    printf("%d ", peek(&pq));
                    pop(&pq);
                }*/


            return 0;
        }
        system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of code to post here. Please do some debugging and narrow down the problem. Perhaps you should start by making some standlone tests of your priority queue. For example, you dereference a null pointer when `data` isn't found in `updateprt`. And you never use the pointer-to-node pointer thing correctly: If you pass a `Node **`, you want to be able to modify the head of the queue in the calling function via the pointer, but you never really do that.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I'm voting to close this for now. Humblefool, if you can, edit the question to include all parts of a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest issue is with your priority queue, which you implement as simple linked list. You seem to be confused about when and how to use a pointer to node pointer.

For example, this function:

```
int isEmpty(Node **head) ...
```

only inspects the list. It doesn't modify it, so it is enough to pass a node pointer:

```
int isEmpty(Node *head) ...
```

This function doesn't modify the contents of the nodes, either, so this could be made explicit:

```
int isEmpty(const Node *head) ...
```

On the other hand, the `push`, `pop` and `updateprt` functions must be able to change the head via a pointer, so they require a pointer to a node pointer. Your `pop` function, which always changes the head, does this. The other functions look like this:

```
void push(Node** head, int d, int p)
{
    Node* start = (*head);

    // ... do stuff with start, leave head alone ...
}
```

Here, you have just used the pointer to node pointer as an overly obscure way to pass in information about the head, but you never modify it (except in the special case of inserting into an ampty list).

Here's how that `push` function should look like:

```
void push(Node **head, int d, int p)
{
    Node *temp = newNode(d, p);

    while (*head && (*head)->priority < p) {
        head = &(*head)->next;
    }

    temp->next = *head;
    *head = temp;
}
```

Note how there aren't any special cases. When you call `push(&queue, ...)`, you pass the address of the head pointer and you can modify the local variable `queue` in the calling function by assigning to `*head`. When you walk through the list with `head = &(*head)->next`, `head` holds the address of the `next` field of the previous node, which you can also modify via `*head`. The pointer to a pointer adds one level of indirection and tells you where you have come from and lets you modify that value.

In the same vein, you can change (and simplify) your `updateptr` function:

```
void updateprt(Node** head, int data)
{
    while (*head && (*head)->data != data) {
        head = &(*head)->next;
    }

    if (*head) pop(head);
}
```

With these changes, your program should work, but there are other things to note:

if (weight[src][dest] != 0 || weight[dest][src] != 0 && w < weight[src][dest]) ...

The condition `(w1 == 0 || w2 == 0 && w < w1)` is parsed as `(w1 == 0 || (w2 == 0 && w < w1))`, which probably isn't what you want. The check for zero is ot done correctly, because you never initialize `weight`. (You could use `calloc` instead of `malloc` to create a zero-initialized array.)`

But why have a separate array of weights at all? You could store the weight with each edge:

```
struct adjlistnode {
    int data;                   // destination vertex
    int weight;
    struct adjlistnode* next;
};
```

The same goes for the arrays:

```
int  Distance[100000], path[50];
```

Both arrays provide one entry for each vertex. The first one is too generous ("I'll allocate a bit more, just in case ..."), the second could be too small. (You don't need the path for the task, but it's always nice to be able to verify it. The variable isn't a path, however, it holds the next step towards the starting point for each vertex.)

The competition rules say that there are at most 3,000 nodes, so you could just dimension your arrays with `[3000]`, but you cold also make them part of the graph structure and allocate according to the number of vertices.

Good luck!

Comment: @M Oehm is my above `updateptr` is correct Iam removing that node which matches with data and then i push again with same data update priority

Comment: No. Does it work? I don't think so. I recommend that you write a small driver `main` that just tests your queue. I'm sure you will find several errors, which you should try to eliminate by debugging.

Comment: (For what it's worth, you have added a special case where you remove the head, but the basic problem is still there: If the value you look for isn't in the list, you eventually dereference `prev` when it is null. That usually leads to a segmentation fault. Also, when you remove a node, you must adjust the `next` of the node before. How do you know where that is? You can also use the code I've shown you above. Your implementation with that incorporates my suggestions above is [here](https://ideone.com/jnORk6).)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your help